# How to handle VBA's keyword arguments in pywin32?

Tags: python, pywin32, xlwings

I'm having an issue trying to use a `pywin32`'s API function on a xlwing aplication for saving a certain Range as a pdf:

```
import xlwings as sw

app  = xw.App(add_book=False, visible=False)
book = app.books.open(fullname=GERALAMINA,
                    update_links=True,
                    read_only=False,
                    ignore_read_only_recommended=True)

sht = book.sheets[0]
sht.range('A1:B10').api.ExportAsFixedFormat(
            Type                 = 0, # xlTypePDF
            FileName             = r'C:/some/path/filename.pdf',
            Quality              = 0, # xlQualityStandard
            IncludeDocProperties = True
        )
```

I used the keywords following [VBA's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat). But got the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-dece9e682dc6> in print_lamina(self)
    345             FileName             = r'C:/some/path/filename.pdf',
    346             Quality              = 0, # xlQualityStandard
--> 347             IncludeDocProperties = True
    348         )
    349 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64         while True:
     65             try:
---> 66                 v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
     67                 if isinstance(v, (CDispatch, CoClassBaseClass, DispatchBaseClass)):
     68                     return COMRetryObjectWrapper(v)

TypeError: ExportAsFixedFormat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'FileName'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with `IncludeDocProperties = 1` but `IncludeDocProperties = True` also works in my case, see [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/boolean-data-type.htm). I tried your code and in my case the parameter `FileName` did not work. I have to use `Filename`, don't ask me why. Here is the code that works for me:

```
import xlwings as xw

app  = xw.App(add_book=False, visible=False)
book = app.books.open(fullname=GERALAMINA,
                    update_links=True,
                    read_only=False,
                    ignore_read_only_recommended=True)

sht = book.sheets[0]
sht.range('A1:B10').api.ExportAsFixedFormat(
            Type                 = 0, # xlTypePDF
            Filename             = r'C:/some/path/filename.pdf',
            Quality              = 0, # xlQualityStandard
            IncludeDocProperties = 1
)
```

By the way it, should be `import xlwings as xw` in your question.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was going crazy with this! The ```ws``` was just a typo, but thank you again anyway!